# setCancelable(false) and onBackPressed conflict

Tags: android

I have a problem

I have a non cancelable custom dialog
which mean this custom dialog can only close if presses buton inside the custom dialog, so it won't cancel on backpress or click outside

I tried `setCancelable(false)` and it works however in my activity I have a onBackPressed and whenever my non cancelable  dialog show onBackPressed wont trigger when I click back button because I think they conflict

is their a solution to do this?

EDIT: The purpose is I want the user to click button ok, or skip inside the custom dialog which means this dialog is required before proceeding to next activity

also in onBackPressed since I am using fragment whenever user press back it changes to previous fragment

sorry for lacking of explanation

my code is this

Dialog

```
dialog_welcome_navigation = DialogUtils.showCustomDialog(context, R.layout.dialog_welcome_navigation);
dialog_welcome_navigation.setCancelable(false); // disable closing dialog with back pressed
dialog_welcome_navigation.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

and the onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Log.d("TAG", "--back--");
}
```

Comment: Why you want onBackPressed to be triggered when you are adding non cancelable Dialog?

Comment: yeah I want....

Comment: @Beginner did you try `dialog.dismiss();` in your `onBackPressed()`

Comment: dialog_welcome_navigation.setCancelable(false);  disables back pressed..you can close dialog only when you press something

Comment: its better to remove .setCancelable(false) from dialog instead of dismissing it on onBackPressed trigger

Comment: @nitinkumarp I have a purpose on doing this, this dialog is non cancellable 
this can only be close when a button click within the custom dialog because it is required before proceeding to another activity, and in onBackPressed it has other code or purpose like for changing fragment etc...

Comment: Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574198/7557205)

Comment: It is working as it should be. What are you trying to achieve here anyways? `onBackPressed` method won't be called unless your dialog is dismissed.

Comment: @Jimit Patel yep you are right sir but I don't want this dialog to be dismiss because it is required be done

Comment: @Beginner Ya I saw your answer. It's good you found out what you wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching I have found a solution thanks to this SO answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251122/3481654

I add a setOnKeyListener on my dialog

```
dialog_welcome_navigation.setOnKeyListener(dialogWelcomeNavigationOnKey);

private DialogInterface.OnKeyListener dialogWelcomeNavigationOnKey = new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            dialog_welcome_navigation.dismiss();

            // move other fragment

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: did you read  this comment  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462203/setcancelablefalse-and-onbackpressed-conflict#comment79879308_46462203